MQTT Error with Android OS 14: "java.lang.SecurityException" in Library
I'm facing a problem with my Android app specifically on devices running Android OS 14. The app crashes with a "java.lang.SecurityException" related to a library file. I'm using the following libraries:
androidx.localbroadcastmanager:localbroadcastmanager:1.1.0
org.eclipse.paho:org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3:1.2.5
org.eclipse.paho:org.eclipse.paho.android.service:1.1.1

Here's a snippet of my AndroidManifest.xml:
<service
    android:exported="false"
    android:name="org.eclipse.paho.android.service.MqttService" />

I'm unsure how to resolve this issue, especially since it's happening in a library file. Any help would be appreciated.
  FATAL EXCEPTION: MQTT Rec: 10001 (Ask Studio Bot)
Process: com.boltuix.androidz, PID: 20263
java.lang.SecurityException: com.boltuix.androidz: One of RECEIVER_EXPORTED or RECEIVER_NOT_EXPORTED should be specified when a receiver isn't being registered exclusively for system broadcasts
    at android.os.Parcel.createExceptionOrNull(Parcel.java:3182)
    at android.os.Parcel.createException(Parcel.java:3166)
    at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:3149)
    at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:3091)
    at android.app.IActivityManager$Stub$Proxy.registerReceiverWithFeature(IActivityManager.java:5784)
    at android.app.ContextImpl.registerReceiverInternal(ContextImpl.java:1853)
    at android.app.ContextImpl.registerReceiver(ContextImpl.java:1793)
    at android.app.ContextImpl.registerReceiver(ContextImpl.java:1781)
    at android.content.ContextWrapper.registerReceiver(ContextWrapper.java:756)
    at org.eclipse.paho.android.service.AlarmPingSender.start(AlarmPingSender.java:74)
    at org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.internal.ClientState.connected(ClientState.java:1214)
    at org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.internal.ClientState.notifyReceivedAck(ClientState.java:1050)
    at org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.internal.CommsReceiver.run(CommsReceiver.java:151)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1012)
Caused by: android.os.RemoteException: Remote stack trace:
    at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.registerReceiverWithFeature(ActivityManagerService.java:14337)
    at android.app.IActivityManager$Stub.onTransact(IActivityManager.java:2615)
    at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.onTransact(ActivityManagerService.java:2798)
    at android.os.Binder.execTransactInternal(Binder.java:1496)
    at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:1440)


Those libraries have not been updated in years, which means they are risky in general. I don't recommend using networking libraries that are not actively maintained. All that said, you can try to add the missing attribute on the <receiver> element via manifest merger in a pinch.

Bolt & Facing same issue did you find solution ?
@CommonsWare any update on this

@Arbaz.in: The library still have not been updated in years. That means they are still risky in general, and I still do not recommend using networking libraries that are not actively maintained.

@CommonsWare please check the solution in answer work for me for above error

I too facing same issue, stuck on this, Got any fixes?

The same issue i faced, After updating of paho library, its worked for me.
In your case use below implementation,
In build.gradle file -
// MQTT Library
implementation 'org.eclipse.paho:org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3:1.2.5'
//new mqtt library that supports android 12 & above
implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
implementation 'com.github.hannesa2:paho.mqtt.android:4.3.beta2'

They resolved issue in latest version.
Thanks.

Finally found the solution after long long  hours R&D
Add RECEIVER_EXPORTED in each registerReceiver attached code for reference.
In AlarmPingSender.java file
Find registerReceiver and update that line with below
 service.registerReceiver(alarmReceiver, new IntentFilter(action), RECEIVER_EXPORTED);

In MqttService.java file
Find registerBroadcastReceivers() and update this line
registerReceiver(networkConnectionMonitor, new IntentFilter(
                ConnectivityManager.CONNECTIVITY_ACTION),RECEIVER_EXPORTED);

In Adnroid Manifest add this permission
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.USE_EXACT_ALARM" />


Hi arbaz, can you share git link, sample mqtt demo (really very helpful for everyone), thank you for your time

How we edit the MqttService.java file, that one from library, in Read only mode.

The solution for me, (like Raghul recommended) was to use the most recent version  of library updated by hannesa2
com.github.hannesa2:paho.mqtt.android:3.6.4
instead of using official
org.eclipse.paho:org.eclipse.paho.android.service:1.1.1
More details on https://github.com/hannesa2/paho.mqtt.android

This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient reputation you will be able to comment on any post; instead, provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker. - From Review
